# Changing text direction in QTableView header

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtreeview

I would like to have a table view in Qt, where the header text would go in vertical direction:

[image: like this table in excel]

Either like in green square or like in red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by providing your own implementation of `QHeaderView`. Here is an example implementation, which overrides the `paintSection` method to paint the text vertically.

```
class MyHeaderView(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(Qt.Horizontal, parent)
        self._font = QtGui.QFont("helvetica", 15)
        self._metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self._font)
        self._descent = self._metrics.descent()
        self._margin = 10

    def paintSection(self, painter, rect, index):
        data = self._get_data(index)
        painter.rotate(-90)
        painter.setFont(self._font)
        painter.drawText(- rect.height() + self._margin,
                         rect.left() + (rect.width() + self._descent) / 2, data)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(0, self._get_text_width() + 2 * self._margin)

    def _get_text_width(self):
        return max([self._metrics.width(self._get_data(i))
                    for i in range(0, self.model().columnCount())])

    def _get_data(self, index):
        return self.model().headerData(index, self.orientation())
```

You can use this class in your view as follows:

```
headerView = MyHeaderView()
tableView.setHorizontalHeader(headerView)
```

And it will result in the following view:

[image]

As a side note I want to add that for regular items, you would rather provide your own item delegate. However, as noted in the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#appearance):

> Each header renders the data for each section itself, and does
>   not rely on a delegate. As a result, calling a header's
>   setItemDelegate() function will have no effect.